# Flask_MongoEngine doesn't work on Webfaction?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, webfaction

I'm currently trying to deploy a website built with the Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to [Webfaction](http://webfaction.com/). I've deployed a MongoDB to which I can succesfully connect from the MongoDB interactive interpreter:

```
[celli@web498 ~]$ mongo localhost:18209/admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.2
connecting to: localhost:18209/admin
> db.auth("awesomeusername", "anawesomepassword")
1
```

When starting the website, it can successfully connect using these credentials in my flask config.py file:

MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'db': 'tc',
    'port': 18209,
    'username': 'awesomeusername',
    'password': 'anawesomepassword',
}

But when I visit a page which does a query I get the error below. This code works perfectly well on another server, so the mistake lies somewhere in either the setup of my MongoDB instance, or in the connection to it. I also find it strange that setting up the connection works fine, but querying it creates this `Authentication failed` error.

Any idea how I can fix this? All tips are welcome!

```
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 758, in decorated_view
 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/tc/app/views/webviews.py", line 220, in myTickets
 userDocs = UserDocument.objects(id__in=[ticket.doc_id for ticket in userTickets])
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/manager.py", line 37, in __get__
 queryset = queryset_class(owner, owner._get_collection())
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 168, in _get_collection
 db = cls._get_db()
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py", line 162, in _get_db
 return get_db(cls._meta.get("db_alias", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME))
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 143, in get_db
 source=conn_settings['authentication_source'])
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 978, in authenticate
 self.connection._cache_credentials(self.name, credentials)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 467, in _cache_credentials
 auth.authenticate(credentials, sock_info, self.__simple_command)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 475, in authenticate
 auth_func(credentials[1:], sock_info, cmd_func)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 450, in _authenticate_default
 return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info, cmd_func)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 238, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
 sasl_start, sasl_continue)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 185, in _scram_sha1_conversation
 res, _ = cmd_func(sock_info, source, sasl_start)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 703, in __simple_command
 helpers._check_command_response(response, None, msg)
File "/home/celli/webapps/tc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 182, in _check_command_response
 raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
OperationFailure: command SON([('saslStart', 1), ('mechanism', 'SCRAM-SHA-1'), ('autoAuthorize', 1), ('payload', Binary('n,,n=awesomeusername,r=NjAxNTEwMjc5MzAy', 0))]) on namespace tc.$cmd failed: Authentication failed.
```

Comment: I don't think MongoDB authenticates when setting up the connection, only when you query the database

Answer (score 0):

[MongoDB's users are per-database](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/#add-a-user). In your example you show that you connect to the `admin` database, but the error message is simply telling you that your user is trying to authenticate with the `tc` database. Probably your user doesn't have a role on `tc`.

(The other possibility is that `tc` is not the database you want to connect to; you need to specify the correct database name in your connection params/string).